# Make: Setting Target Specific Variables With Different Goals

Tags: makefile

I'm building a makefile that will be used to build a release or debug target library.  I want to place the object and auto-generated dependancy files into either a debug or release directory structure, depending on the requested makefile goal.  I don't want to specify a testable make command-line argument (i.e. DBG=1), but would prefer to run make -f Makefile, or make -f Makefiel dbg for release and debug target goals, respectively.  Got that part down.  I understand that I can't assign a target-specific variable containing the name of the object dir (either release or debug) that can be used as part of the Target specification in a rule, like I did in the example shown below.  In this example, OBJDIR is the target-specific variable I would like to set depending on the build goal.  For that reason, in this example, $(OBJDIR) is empty in the target rule $(OBJDIR)/%.o.  Any recommendations on how to perform the suggested steps nicely?  (The example shown is simply a copy/paste unverified example...syntax is not verified...in fact, I can't get the tabs to appear correctly...I'm hoping to get some implementation ideas).  (Also, $(OBJDIR) is not set in the clean target as shown...since it is not in the dbg/all target dependancy heirarchy...thoughts?)  Thanks in advance.

Makefile:

```
OBJS    := a.o b.o c.o  
SRCS    := $(OBJS:.o=.c)  

-- Set up the release and the debug directory paths and object filenames  
RELEASE_DIR := ./release  
RELEASE_OBJ := $(OBJS:%=$(RELEASE_DIR)/%)  
DEBUG_DIR   := ./debug  
DEBUG_OBJ   := $(OBJS:%=$(DEBUG_DIR)/%)  

.PHONY : all dbg 

all: CFLAGS = -O3  
all: OBJDIR := RELEASE_DIR  
all: df     := $(RELEASE_DIR)/$(*F)  
all: init_release lib1.so  

dbg: CFLAGS = -g -O0  
dbg: OBJDIR := DEBUG_DIR  
dbg: df     := $(DEBUG_DIR)/$(*F)  
dbg: init_debug lib1.so  

Lib1.so: $(OBJ)  

init_release:  
    -@mkdir -p $(RELEASE_DIR)  

init_debug:  
    -@mkdir -p $(DEBUG_DIR)  

lib1.so: $(OBJ)  
    @echo '--------------------------------------------------------------'
    @echo linking $@  
    @gcc -shared -o lib1.so $(OBJ)  

-Compile including advance dependancy generation alg, per Tom Tromey:
    # http://make.paulandlesley.org/autodep.html  
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c  
    echo $@    
    echo $(OBJDIR)  
    echo compiling $@  
    $(COMPILE.c) -MD -o $@ $<  
    cp $(df).d $(df).P; \  
    sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\$$//' \  
             -e '/^$$/ d' -e 's/$$/ :/' < $(df).d >> $(df).P; \  
    rm -f $(df)/$*.d  

# If the goal is "clean", don't include these to avoid trying to build them
ifneq($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)  
-include $(SRCS:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.P)
endif  

clean:  
    -@rm -f    $(OBJDIR)/*.[Pdo] lib1.so
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Target specific variables can be tricky. Use indirection instead. Make has lots of syntax to cut-down on boilerplate text. `.SECONDEXPANSION` is often good. A sketch:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
${DEBUG_OBJ} ${RELEASE_OBJ}: $$(patsubst %.o,%.c,$${@F})
    gcc ${copts-${@D}} -c $< -o $@
```

Here we tell make that `./release/a.o` depends on `a.c`. When make decides to build `./release/a.o` it expands the shell line. As it does so, `${@D}` is naturally `release`, so make carries on and expands `${copts-release}` which you will have defined usefully.

Similarly, when producing `./debug/a.o` make expands `${copts-debug}`.

Copious use of `$(warning [blah])`, `$(error [blah blah])` and the mandatory `--warn-undefined-variables` will help you get this right.

Comment: Nice. So, to add to the mix, is there a way to parametrically set OBJDIR to reflect a similar expansion (release or debug subdir) in the following from the original example? (I'm kind of surprised this is not a more common implementation in the makefile realm...different build configurations and squirreling the objects/dependancies in their own subdirs to reduce build time for larger projects)  
ifneq($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)  
 -include $(SRCS:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.P)  
endif

Comment: @user654077: Hard to read your comment. I'd just say `include` all the deps unconditionally. It's not going to hurt. Don't bother checking `MAKECMDGOALS` first—that seems more than a little fragile. (`-include $(patsubst %.o,%.P,${DEBUG_OBJ} ${RELEASE_OBJ})`.)

Comment: Thanks so much...Works great so far. One more extension question & I think I'll have this licked. Perhaps, instead of simply putting the build configuration into .debug or .release, the desired object dir is more like "./LibName/.debug" and "./LibName/.release". Using your .SECONDEXPANSION solution, I would like to resolve the ${copts-${@D}} to simply .debug or .release, not LibName/.debug, etc. Couldn't find a way to extract just the "last subdir" portion of the OBJDIR. Thoughts?

Comment: @user654077: Several thoughts. `$(notdir $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir ${var})))`; or maybe `$(lastword $(subst /, ,$(dir ${var})))`; then again `$(patsubst ./LibName/%,%,${var})`. You might find _Static Pattern Rules_ really useful as you can get `$*` to match bits you need. TMTOWDI as the perl folks might say.

Comment: Awesome...used a variation of your second suggestion.  Works like a champ! Many thanks (for the tips & suggested reading, as well).

Answer (score 1):

The Makefile you wrote is not valid, and it will not generate your targets as you expect. For instance, you cannot set the `CFLAGS` variable in the targets definitions `all` and `dbg`.

The only solution I can think of is to call make with the same Makefile defining the `DBG` variable as you wish. E.g.:

```
ifdef DBG
CFLAGS = -O0 -ggdb
OBJDIR = dbgdir
else
CFLAGS = -O2
OBJDIR = reldir
endif

all: $(OBJDIR)/target
    #Your commands here

dbg:
    $(MAKE) DBG=1
```

With this, if you call `make`, you have the release build. If you call `make dbg` you have the release build.

Comment: Yeah, in my "real" implementation, CFLAGS += those flags...I just cut & pasted & edited up for example purposes).  I did think of the recursive make solution, but was hoping for another, more elegant approach.  I found something close in another thread: